# Obtaining a Client Id for WPF application using Facebook API

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to add a client ID to my application to use the Facebook oAuth api 
for login.

It gives me an app ID but no client ID as the application needs to be published.
The problem is that to get a client ID, the application needs to be published but there is noavailable platform option for WPF.

Is there any work around for this?

[image: dev dash]

The options shown for release platforms don't include WPF.
[image: platform choices]

Comment: "Windows application" doesn't work for you? I highly doubt that Facebook is going to include every single presentation framework language in their choices. =)

Comment: @J.Steen any idea how to get a client ID for a WPF app? I have seen other examples that have a client ID in their WPF app, wondering how they got that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an old question, but couldn't find any answer online.

Turns out you have to click on the "Advanced" tab and then scroll down to "Embedded Browser OAuth Login" and enable it

[image]